# Upper Bound for an Equation

Tags: inequality

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be the elements of $R$ and $g(x)$ is a continuous function. We are given the following:
\begin{align*}
x_2^2 \leq x_2g(x_2) \leq Kx_2^2 \\ 
|x_1x_2| \leq \frac{x_1^2}{2} + \frac{x_2^2}{2} 
\end{align*}
where $K > 1$.

I try to show the below inequality holds:
$-g^2(x_2) + \epsilon x_2g(x_2) - \epsilon x_1 g(x_2) \leq -x^2_2 + K\epsilon x^2_2  + K\epsilon |x_1 x_2|$

where $\epsilon < 1$.

Obviously $\epsilon x_2g(x_2) \leq  K\epsilon x^2_2$ follows from $x_2g(x_2) \leq Kx_2^2$ but I have no idea for the others.

Comment: Can $\epsilon$ be negative?

Comment: @Prometheus Yes.

Comment: Then the statement $\epsilon x_2g(x_2) \leq  K\epsilon x^2_2$ might not be true then, since for negative numbers, the inequality flips.

Answer (score 1):

$|g(x_2)| \geq |x_2| \Rightarrow g^2(x_2) \geq x_2 \Rightarrow -g^2(x_2) \leq -x_2^2$

$\epsilon x_2g(x_2) \leq  K\epsilon x^2_2$ has been shown by you.

Last one is the one left to prove.